# Twitch API search stream via Javascript AJAX - get all streams

Tags: javascript, ajax, twitch

I have an ajax function hitting the Twitch API to find "Starcraft" streams.

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET', 
  url: 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/search/streams?q=starcraft',
  headers: {'Client-ID': 'xxx'},
  success: function(json) {
    console.log(json);
}});
```

This returns `Object {_total: 108, _links: Object, streams: Array[9]}`. I want `streams` array to hold all streams (all 108).

I've tried adding limit and offset to url like so:
`https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/search/streams?limit=100&offset=0&q=starcraft` but this will obviously only work for cases where there are under 100 streams. Anyone familiar with the Twitch API, is there like a `limit=max` kind of thing? If not, what is the workaround?

Comment: Looking at the doc... you did look at the doc first right? It appears the max is 100: https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/api/v3/streams#get-streams

Comment: @JonP yes i looked at the doc.....the question asks if there is a workaround?

Comment: So make two requests, one offset, and combine the arrays?

Comment: @Harangue i see, good idea. however, for situations where there is more than 200 streams, will i be forced to create 3, then 4 and so on?

Comment: @DragonOne Yep. That's the point of a request limit - to make sure that Twitch's API servers can manage capacity appropriately.

Comment: Basically there is no way to make the `streams` array in the return hold more than the API developers declare as the maximum. Have a local array, call the API in a loop until the size of your local array is the same as `_total`.

Comment: @JonP thank you so much

Comment: @Harangue thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is based on my comment to your question and should get you started. I;ve worked on the assumption that `offest` is eqivalent to page. Note that the code is untested and a starting point only.

Also make sure to handle a failure from the ajax call so you don't get stuck in an infinate loop.

```
fucntion GetAllStreams(){
    var arrStreams = [];
    var offset = 0;
    var total = -1;

    while(total < 0 || arrStreams.length < total)
    {
        $.ajax({
          type: 'GET', 
          url: 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/search/streams?limit=100&offset=' + offset++ + '&q=starcraf',
          headers: {'Client-ID': 'xxx'},
          success: function(json) {
            arrStreams.push(json.streams);
            console.log(json);
            console.log(arrStreams);
        }});
    }   

    retrun arrStreams;
}
```

Comment: This makes sense. Thank you. I'm wondering though, you said `offset` is equivalent to page. What does page mean in this situation?

Comment: I think, and the doc wasn't clear on this, that the offset, is the next set of streams, and is 0 based. E.g with a limit of 20, an offset of 0 would return the first set of 20, an offset of 1 would return the next set of 20 etc. The other option is that you would need to offset by mulitples of your limit, E.g: 100, 200 etc. You'll need to run a couple of tests to see what actually happens.

Comment: So I found out that the `_total` does not equal to `streams.length`, even when I try to get the max length:

Object {_total: 81, _links: Object, streams: Array[75]}

This object is received after hitting this API: `https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/search/streams?limit=100&offset=0&q=starcraft` 

Are you familiar with the Twitch API? Can you see where the disconnect is here? With `limit=100`, the `streams` array should have 81 elements, not 75 right?